# How to open port 3306 on Google Colab with UFW, IPTables

Tags: google-colaboratory, ufw

I have installed MySQL in Google Colab and have been successful in accessing from the command line using

```
!mysql -e " --- any valid database command ---- "
```

My next task is make this MySQL server visible from a remote client. This requires, making a change in the mysqld.cnf file, which I have done and then open up port 3306 for remote access. Once this happens, then I will use an ngrok tunnel to expose port 3306 on the public internet and use a MySQL client (like HeidiSQL).

I am unable to open the port 3306.

I have installed ufw using

```
!apt install ufw
```

But when I try

```
!ufw status
```

I get

```
ERROR: problem running iptables: iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

However, when I try to install IPTABLES, I get

```
iptables is already the newest version (1.6.1-2ubuntu2).
iptables set to manually installed.
```

Finally, I try

```
!whoami
```

I get

```
root
```

So I am root and iptables is at the latest version and yet ufw is not running. Obviously, I am doing something wrong. Would be grateful if someone can help me, sort this problem

Answer (score -1):

Strangely, enough, it works WITHOUT having to OPEN the ports. So this question has become meaningless!

I just tried accessing the MySQL server running in Google Colab from an external MySQL client ( HeidiSQL) and it worked perfectly well.

Comment: Amazing. Doesn't address the initial question about actually opening ports, though